# Javascript- prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript

I don't understand something>Let's take a look at MDN's example:

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;

  if (price < 0) {
    throw RangeError('Cannot create product ' +
                      this.name + ' with a negative price');
  }

  return this;
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}

Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
Food.prototype.constructor = Food; // Reset the constructor from Product to Food
```

Why I must write this part:

```
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
    Food.prototype.constructor = Food;
```

Isn't the  `Product.call(this, name, price);` already copied that property(Prototype) from Product to Food?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: No, that `Product.call(…)` has nothing to do with the prototype. It only initialises the `name` and `price` properties of the instance

Comment: Why is it? Because prototype is not in arguments?

Comment: Because that's how JavaScript works.

Comment: That's weird. PHP OOP is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is just how you do pseudoclassical instantiation of a class in JavaScript. Lets first see what happens when you just do the first part, but lets add a bit for clarification:

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;

  if (price < 0) {
    throw RangeError('Cannot create product ' +
                      this.name + ' with a negative price');
  }

  return this;
}

Product.prototype.declare = function () {
  console.log('I like ' + this.name);
} 

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}
```

Run this in a console and and run `console.dir(Product)` vs `console.dir(Food)`. Food has some of the same properties as Product. However, `Food` doesn't have access to the method "declare" that is on `Product`'s prototype. Thus, we need to set `Food`'s prototype. Run this in console after the above code:

```
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
```

run `console.dir` for `Food` again. Now, Food has a prototype that has the same properties/methods as `Product`. However, the prototype's constructor is now 'Product'. The last step to fix this is setting `Food.prototype.constructor` so `Food`'s constructor is once again `Food`, but with all of the properties/methods of `Product`.

```
Food.prototype.constructor = Food;
```

It's a strange but logical process to attaining full inheritance with pseudoclassical instantiation in JavaScript.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't understand why Call method didn't copied prototype of Product. After all prototype is just another property of Product object and it should copy that property.

Comment: I don't see method declare in Food.prototype when I do all that.

Comment: It should be under the __proto__ property of Food (because it's inheriting from Product). Try instantiating a new `Food` object:

    `var steak = new Food('steak', 50);`

Then run:


    `steak.declare();`

Comment: The `call` method does not just copy the object over. It just executes the function. Thus, it will execute whatever is in your function but not any values attached to it's prototype. `call` is a function method that is not specific to object instantiation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call.

Comment: Ok, I see the declare method now. Tnx... I don't get what are you triying to say here: "Thus, it will execute whatever is in your function but not any values attached to it's prototype"...Why?

Comment: That's just how JavaScript works. `call` executes the function `Product`. `Product.prototype` is not within the function code.